# How to setup imports and dependencies between modules in the same python package

Tags: python, module, package

I am writing a library in python. It has one package and 3 modules, such as

```
mypackage
    __init__.py
    utils.py
    fileio.py
    math.py
```

If I just leave the `__init__.py` empty, my users must figure out which functions are in which modules, which is annoying. The fact that I have three modules is an implementation detail that is not important.

Maybe I should import the main functions into the `__init__.py`, like this

```
from .utils import create_table
from .fileio import save_rows, load_rows
from .math import matrix_inverse
```

so that my users can just do

```
import mypackage as myp

rows = myp.load_rows()
```

Is that best practice?

What about the alternative to put ALL symbols into the `__init__.py`, such as

```
from .utils import *
from .fileio import *
from .math import *
```

And if there are any functions that I *don't* want to expose, I will prefix them with underscore. Is that better?  It certainly is easier for me.

What if the `fileio.py` needs to call some functions in the `utils.py`?  I could put

```
from .utils import *
```

into the `fileio.py`, but won't that create a circular or redundant reference? What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe I should import the main functions into the **init**.py, like this [...] Is that best practice?

I wouldn't say there is a "best practice", it depends on the specific case, but this is surely pretty common: you define a bunch of stuff in each module, and import the relevant ones in `__init__`. This is an easy way to not bother the users with remembering which submodule has the needed function, however it can get pretty annoying if you have a lot of functions to import from each module.

> What about the alternative to put ALL symbols into the **init**.py, such as
>
> ```
> from .utils import *
> from .fileio import *
> from .math import *
> ```

You most likely ***don't*** want to do this. This will import everything in user scripts, including other imported modules and internal functions. You should avoid it.

> What if the fileio.py needs to call some functions in the utils.py? [...] won't that create a circular or redundant reference?

Yeah, that is something that can happen and you usually want to avoid it at all costs. If you need some functions from `utils.py` in `fileio.py`, you should import them explicitly as `from .utils import x, y, z`. Remember to also always use *relative* imports when importing things between modules of the same package (i.e. use `from .utils import x`, not `from package.utils import x`).

---

A good compromise between these two options you mention which solves most of the above problems (although not circular imports, you would have to avoid those yourself) would be to define an [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) list inside each one of your modules to specify which functions should be exported when using `from x import *`, like this:

```py
# utils.py

import sys

__all__ = ['user_api_one', 'user_api_two']

def user_api_one():
    ...

def user_api_two():
    ...

def internal_function():
    ...
```

If you properly define an `__all__` list in all your modules, then in your `__init__.py` you will be able to safely do:

```py
from .utils import *
from .fileio import *
from .math import *
```

This will *only import relevant functions* (for example `user_api_one` and `user_api_two` for `utils`, and not `internal_function` nor `sys`).